# Can we get real client IP in the request to a service running on AKS?

Tags: azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with nginx internal ingress and linkerd (as sidecar)

I also have an Asp.Net Core service deployed there that reports telemetry to an App Insights bucket which does NOT mask client IPs.

However, the reported client IP is of an AKS node rather than the actual client.

I ran 3 requests (using curl on the client machine) and got the following `client_IP` addresses:
[image]
These are all IPs of AKS nodes:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get node -o wide | grep -E '10\.16\.232\.(5|7|8)'
aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   Ready    agent   34d   v1.28.3   10.16.232.8   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-1052-azure   containerd://1.7.5-1
aks-linux-21546199-vmss000001          Ready    agent   34d   v1.28.3   10.16.232.5   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-1052-azure   containerd://1.7.5-1
aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000       Ready    agent   34d   v1.28.3   10.16.232.7   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS   5.15.0-1052-azure   containerd://1.7.5-1
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

The returned IPs are all over the place. `10.16.232.5` corresponds to a system node, `10.16.232.7` - to a node dedicated to running the various tools, including the nginx ingress:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get pod -A -o wide | grep -E 'internal-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller.+aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000'
system-d-internal-ingress          internal-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-558f8f48d7-fkm99        1/1     Running     0              29d     10.254.3.46    aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000       <none>           <none>
system-d-internal-ingress          internal-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-558f8f48d7-scdf9        1/1     Running     0              29d     10.254.3.47    aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000       <none>           <none>
system-d-internal-ingress          internal-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-558f8f48d7-vd45m        1/1     Running     0              29d     10.254.3.48    aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000       <none>           <none>
system-d-internal-ingress          internal-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-558f8f48d7-xm4wt        1/1     Running     0              29d     10.254.3.49    aks-toolsnp1-41813426-vmss000000       <none>           <none>
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Finally, `10.16.232.8` maps to the node where the service itself is running along with the linkerd sidecar image:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get pod -n aida-dev -o wide | grep -E 'aida-api.+aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000'
aida-api-77586856d-rmmw2                                          2/2     Running   0              16h    10.254.2.88    aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   <none>           <none>
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

This is all very confusing. Why the result is so inconsistent?
I can understand if the client IP is that of the application node, because linkerd is a proxy and can replace the incoming client IP.
I can understand if the client IP is that of the tools node, because nginx is also a proxy and thus can also replace the client IP.
But I do not understand how come we have 3 different possibilities? And in general - is it possible to get the real client IP?

Comment: It is possible to get the real client IP in a request to a service running on AKS. The reason why the reported client IP is of an AKS node rather than the actual client is because linkerd is a proxy and can replace the incoming client IP, and nginx is also a proxy and thus can also replace the client IP. The returned IPs are inconsistent because the requests are being routed through different nodes. To get the real client IP, you can configure the nginx ingress controller to use the use-forwarded-headers annotation.

Comment: This will forward the original client IP address to the backend service. Another option is to use the X-Forwarded-For header to pass the client IP address. This header can be added to the request by the proxy server.

Comment: References:

-   [Troubleshoot connection issues to pods or services within an AKS cluster (internal traffic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/troubleshoot-connection-pods-services-same-cluster#troubleshoot-connection-issues-to-pods-or-services-within-an-aks-cluster-internal-traffic)
-   [Troubleshoot connection issues to an app that's hosted on an AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/connection-issues-application-hosted-aks-cluster#basic-network-flow-for-applications-on-aks)

Comment: @Arko - thanks for the hint. Could you provide an answer with more details? Thanks again.